# Disable a field depending on a Picklist value in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

The field

```
<div class="slds-truncate" title="">
    <apex:inputField style="width:90px; " value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}"/>
 </div>
```

needs to be disabled when

```
<div class="slds-truncate" title="">
    <apex:inputField value="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c}"/>
</div>
```

is Equal to Product_A

Assuming that **Products_Offer__c** is picklist and has a value of *Product_A* and *Product_B*

VF Page

```
<apex:form id="formId">
            <apex:actionFunction name="deleteProductAF" action="{!deleteProductMethod}" status="status" oncomplete="reloadPage();">
                <apex:param name="scheduleIdToDelete" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <body >
                <apex:slds />
                <div class="slds-scope slds-m-top_x-large">
                    <apex:outputPanel id="tableId">
                        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-p-vertical_x-small">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                                    <th class="" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Product</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Total Fee</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Start Date</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Duration (Months)</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="" scope="col"> 
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
```

Apex Class

```
    public with sharing class OpportunitySchedulePageExtension {
    public Opportunity currentOpportunity {get; set;}
    public List<Revenue_Schedule__c> revenueSchedules {get; set;}
    public String redirectUrl {get; set;}
    public opportunitySchedulePageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
        currentOpportunity = (Opportunity) standardController.getRecord();

        currentOpportunity = [SELECT Id, CurrencyIsoCode FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: currentOpportunity.Id];

        redirectUrl = standardController.view().getUrl();

        revenueSchedules = new List<Revenue_Schedule__c>();
        revenueSchedules = [SELECT Id,Products_Offer__c, Total_Amount__c, Start_Date__c, Duration__c
                                   FROM Revenue_Schedule__c WHERE Opportunity__c =: currentOpportunity.Id];

        if(revenueSchedules.isEmpty()){
            Revenue_Schedule__c newRevenueSchedule1 = new Revenue_Schedule__c();
            newRevenueSchedule1.Opportunity__c = currentOpportunity.Id;
            newRevenueSchedule1.CurrencyIsoCode = currentOpportunity.CurrencyIsoCode;
            revenueSchedules.add(newRevenueSchedule1);
        }                             
    }

    public void addItemRow(){
        if(revenueSchedules.size() != 4){
            Revenue_Schedule__c newRevenueSchedule = new Revenue_Schedule__c();
            newRevenueSchedule.Opportunity__c = currentOpportunity.Id;
            newRevenueSchedule.CurrencyIsoCode = currentOpportunity.CurrencyIsoCode;
            revenueSchedules.add(newRevenueSchedule);
        }
    }

    public void saveRevenueSchedules(){
        upsert revenueSchedules;
    }

    public void deleteProductMethod(){
        String scheduleIdToDelete = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('scheduleIdToDelete');

        if(scheduleIdToDelete != ''){
            Revenue_Schedule__c revenueScheduleToDelete = new Revenue_Schedule__c(Id=scheduleIdToDelete);
            delete revenueScheduleToDelete;

        }

    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: so, 1) what specifically is not working and, 2) more importantly, to get the most from the Community; strip out unnecessary parts of the code/VF page. See [ask] and then use [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of coding this would be using an output field and rendered attributes:

```
<div class="slds-truncate" title="">
    <apex:inputField style="width:90px;" value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c != 'Product_B'}"/>
    <apex:outputField style="width:90px;" value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c == 'Product_B'}"/>
 </div>
```

You will also want to add rerender on change, I assume, you'll want to use apex action regions. [Apex action region documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm)

```
<apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c}" id="product">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlockEncapsulatingYourStartDateFields" status="status"/>
        </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: Hi @jmdohn thank you for the response. I'm quite new to coding so I'm still learning. Sorry for this stupid question, should I add both of the code in the VF page? Appreciate your help here!

Comment: That depends entirely on your use case.  If you're requiring a change based on field updates, you would need to add both recommendations.  You needs to update the rerender in actionRegion to match your encapsulating components to rerender as well.

Comment: Please see my code update, I don't have a pageBlock is it still possible in my scenario?

Comment: My goal here is that when I change the Picklist value to Product_B without saving any records the Duration field will be disabled.

Is it possible?